# Sending Laravel Sanctum API call from Nuxt3 setup works but the same call from server/api directory returns 401

Tags: http-status-code-401, laravel-sanctum, nuxt3

I have defined two functions in my `<script setup>` on my login page:

```
async function getUser(){

    const xsrf = useCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
   
    await useFetch("http://localhost/api/user", {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrf.value
        },
        credentials: "include"
    })

}

async function getUserApi(){

    await useFetch("/api/user")

}
```

The `getUserApi` function calls Nuxt3 api url which is defined in `server/api` directory in `user.get.js` file:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    
    let xsrf = getCookie(event, 'XSRF-TOKEN') || 0

    const data = await $fetch('http://localhost/api/user', {
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': xsrf
        },
        credentials: "include"
    })

    return data;
    
})
```

The `getUser` function works and returns authenticated user, but the `getUserApi` returns 401 unauthenticated error.

So I think that my Laravel application is set up correctly, but something has to be wrong with the api call from `server/api` directory.

I tried to add origin header: https://github.com/unjs/ofetch/issues/149 and also referer header: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/12346 but without success.

What could be the problem?